# Why is Microsoft Graph more restrictive?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

In outlook I can lookup all users in my organisation, including phone number, address etc.
I guess using EWS I could do the same... 
With Azure AD graph (https://graph.windows.net) I can get ALL(!) properties on all (GAL) users as well - without the option to select a smaller property subset…

In Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com) I can get all users (GAL), but not (all) properties like phone number, title etc. without an admin allows access… Why is this different (more restricted) than the other APIs ?

ex. the permission; Directory.AccessAsUser.All (Access the directory as the signed-in user)

- In Microsoft Graph user is UNABLE to consent
- In Azure AD Graph - does NOT require admin

Using the /me/people (in preview) in Microsoft Graph I can get all properties on a lot of users in my organisation - but not all. And I might get some users that my nearest colleague can’t (why? - is it still buggy)

Every one tell you to use Microsoft Graph but it seems to be more restricted than the old APIs

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to know a little more about the restrictive nature that you are describing. For the most part (with respect to Directory/Azure AD), Microsoft Graph exposes the same data secured by the same permissions model as Azure AD Graph.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions for more details on the available user permissions and what they allow.

What you might be seeing with Microsoft Graph is the fact that when you query the /users entity set in v1.0 (i.e. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`) Microsoft Graph will return only a key set of user properties by default.  The `user` entity type is pretty big, and growing all the time - it has more than 40 properties and 25 navigation properties.  Serializing and de-serializing large objects, especially when paging collections can be expensive and non-performant, both for the client and for the Microsoft Graph service.  Hence we return a default set. If you want other properties then you need to use the `$select` parameter.  For example:  `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName, officeLocation,postalCode,state`.  This is documented here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_get for example, but we are working on making some improvements to the documentation in this area too. If you want to see the full set of properties exposed by the Microsoft Graph `user` entity type, please look at the schema here: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata.

[NOTE:  $select is not supported in Azure AD Graph API, so we always return the full set].

The people API - `../me/people` is about the people who you (the signed-in user) communicate with most often - it could also contain people outside of your organization. Hence, the list of people is likely specific and different for each user (even colleagues). It also is not the full directory of users in your organization.

I'd also like to get to the bottom of why you are seeing a difference in terms of consent - Directory.AccessAsUser.All always requires admin consent for web apps (for both Microsoft and Azure AD Graph).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Using both Graph Explorers I can more users and 'not-null' properties in the Azure AD Graph Explorer than in the Microsoft Graph Explorer... I cannot use Microsoft Graph to get phone numbers, job title etc. but these properties are filled in the Azure AD Graph Explorer...

The default set (contains 11 properties) actually contains all the properties that I need for the moment. It returns informations in; id, displayName, givenName, mail, surname and userprincipalname - while businessPhones, jobTitle, mobilePhone, officeLocation (and preferredLangiage) is empty for ALL users.

Comment: We won't use the /people API anyways but it did give us the missing properties... Seems to only return max 1000 records - but is that 1000 (pr. user) nomatter what filter I'm using or is it pr. filter(?)

Comment: I got a 'Azure AD only applications' (Web app / API) in the Azure Portal. In the 'Required permissions' section I have added access for both 'Microsoft Graph' and 'Windows Azure Active Directory (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory)'. In the 'Delegate permissions' section I see the following: 

* Microsoft Graph: 'Access directory as the signed in user' has a green icon with a 'Yes' as 'requires admin'

* Windows Azure AD: 'Access the directory as the signed-in user' has a red icon and 'No' as 'requires admin'

Comment: To add to this, in the [AAD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) I'm able to query `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users` and see multiple phone numbers per user: `facsimileTelephoneNumber`, `telephoneNumber`, and `mobile`. But in [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and I query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` I see an empty array for `businessPhones`, and a null `mobilePhone` for every user. I made sure to compare a user who displays a phone number in AAD Graph to their results in MS Graph.

Comment: I think it's a permission issue. I noticed I'm able to see my business and mobile phone number when I query MS Graph with /users/<myEmail>, but my coworker cannot when making the same query and vice versa. I'm not able to test it right now, but I think the Admin permission of "Read all users' full profiles" would be needed to read these phone numbers.

Comment: Correct.  You need to grant the app (Graph Explorer) User.Read.All permissions to read other user's full profile.  By default Graph Explorer asks for User.ReadBasic.All which allows you to read a limited set of properties from other users.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions. AAD Graph Explorer requires a broader permission that allows you to read full profiles.  Like I said earlier, the underlying directory data store is the same.

Comment: This is why we ended up using AAD for data (and MS Graph for delta GAL)...